# How to make drag and drop work between empty grids?

Tags: reactjs

I have an implementation of dragging and dropping between two grids with multiple selection and row reordering. Currently, it works, however, if one of the Grids is empty, the drag and drop does not work. How can I make it work if one of the grids is empty as well? I saw that the component renders a GridNoRecords component that allows the developer to customize the tex shown, when there are no records available, I attempted to hook the dragStart and dragOver on the onDrop and onDragOver however that did not work. What am I doing wrong and how can I make the drag and drop work even with an empty grid? Here is the main.jsx code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  Grid,
  GridNoRecords,
  GridColumn as Column,
} from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import { DragAndDrop } from '@progress/kendo-react-common';

import { DraggableRow } from './draggable-row';
import { SelectionCell } from './selection-cell';
import { DragHint } from './drag-hint';

import products from './products.json';
import { Product } from './interfaces';

export const ReorderContext = React.createContext<{
  reorder: (dataItem: Product, direction: 'before' | 'after' | null) => void;
  dragStart: (dataItem: Product) => void;
  dragEnd: (dataItem?: Product) => void;
}>({ reorder: () => {}, dragStart: () => {}, dragEnd: () => {} });
export const SelectionContext = React.createContext<[Product[], any]>([
  [],
  () => {},
]);
export const IsSelectedContext = React.createContext<boolean>(false);
export const DragHintContext =
  React.createContext<React.RefObject<HTMLElement> | null>(null);
export const GridContext = React.createContext<React.RefObject<Grid> | null>(
  null
);

const App = () => {
  const grid = React.useRef(null);
  const hint = React.useRef(null);
  const [gridData1, setGridData1] = React.useState(products.slice(0, 0));
  const [gridData2, setGridData2] = React.useState(products.slice(31, 60));
  const [selection, setSelection] = React.useState<Product[]>([]);
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = React.useState<Product | null>(null);

  const reorder = (relativeDataItem: any, direction: 'before' | 'after') => {
    let firstGridData = gridData1.slice();
    let secondGridData = gridData2.slice();

    const insertToFirst = firstGridData.some(
      (i) => i.ProductID === relativeDataItem.ProductID
    );

    const insertToSecond = secondGridData.some(
      (i) => i.ProductID === relativeDataItem.ProductID
    );

    firstGridData = removeDataItems(selection, firstGridData);
    secondGridData = removeDataItems(selection, secondGridData);

    if (insertToFirst) {
      firstGridData = insertDataItems(
        selection,
        relativeDataItem,
        direction,
        firstGridData
      );
    }

    if (insertToSecond) {
      secondGridData = insertDataItems(
        selection,
        relativeDataItem,
        direction,
        secondGridData
      );
    }

    setGridData1(firstGridData);
    setGridData2(secondGridData);
    setActiveItem(null);
  };

  const insertDataItems = (
    itemsToInsert,
    relativeDataItem,
    direction,
    collection
  ) => {
    let reorderedData = collection.slice();
    let nextIndex = reorderedData.findIndex(
      (p) => p.ProductID === relativeDataItem.ProductID
    );

    reorderedData.splice(
      Math.max(nextIndex + (direction === 'before' ? 0 : 1), 0),
      0,
      ...itemsToInsert
    );

    return reorderedData;
  };

  const removeDataItems = (itemsToRemove, collection) => {
    if (
      collection.some((i) =>
        itemsToRemove.some((s) => s.ProductID === i.ProductID)
      )
    ) {
      const newData = collection.filter(
        (i) => !itemsToRemove.some((s) => s.ProductID === i.ProductID)
      );
      return newData;
    }
    return collection;
  };

  const dragStart = (dataItem: any) => {
    setActiveItem(dataItem);
  };

  const dragEnd = () => {
    setActiveItem(null);
  };

  return (
    <GridContext.Provider value={grid}>
      <DragHintContext.Provider value={hint}>
        <ReorderContext.Provider value={{ reorder, dragStart, dragEnd }}>
          <SelectionContext.Provider value={[selection, setSelection]}>
            <DragAndDrop>
              <Grid
                ref={grid}
                style={{ height: '400px' }}
                data={gridData1}
                dataItemKey={'ProductID'}
                rowRender={(row, rowProps) => (
                  <DraggableRow elementProps={row.props} {...rowProps} />
                )}
              >
                <GridNoRecords>
                  <div style={{ height: 350, backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>
                    Drag items here
                  </div>
                </GridNoRecords>
                <Column title="" width="80px" cell={SelectionCell} />
                <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="60px" />
                <Column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="200px" />
                <Column field="Category.CategoryName" title="CategoryName" />
                <Column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80px" />
                <Column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80px" />
              </Grid>
              <hr />
              <Grid
                ref={grid}
                style={{ height: '400px' }}
                data={gridData2}
                dataItemKey={'ProductID'}
                rowRender={(row, rowProps) => (
                  <DraggableRow elementProps={row.props} {...rowProps} />
                )}
              >
                <GridNoRecords>
                  <div
                    style={{ height: 350, backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
                    onDrop={dragStart}
                    onDragOver={dragEnd}
                  >
                    Drag items here
                  </div>
                </GridNoRecords>
                <Column title="" width="80px" cell={SelectionCell} />
                <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="60px" />
                <Column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="200px" />
                <Column field="Category.CategoryName" title="CategoryName" />
                <Column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80px" />
                <Column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80px" />
              </Grid>
              <DragHint
                ref={hint}
                portal={grid}
                className="k-card"
                style={{ display: activeItem ? undefined : 'none' }}
              >
                {activeItem && activeItem.ProductName}
                {selection.length > 1 && (
                  <div
                    style={{
                      position: 'absolute',
                      pointerEvents: 'none',
                      bottom: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      background: 'red',
                      padding: 8,
                      width: 32,
                      color: 'white',
                      borderRadius: '50%',
                      transform: 'translate(50%, 50%)',
                    }}
                  >
                    +{selection.length - 1}
                  </div>
                )}
              </DragHint>
            </DragAndDrop>
          </SelectionContext.Provider>
        </ReorderContext.Provider>
      </DragHintContext.Provider>
    </GridContext.Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

And here is a small reproducible example that showcases the behavior:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kkucf8-yjrpth?file=app%2Fmain.tsx,app%2Fdraggable-row.tsx